# Crystal Reports - Check what is the currext export type

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2010, crystal-reports-xi, crystal-reports-8.5

In the formula editor, is there a way to see what is the current report export type? That is, is there a way to see if the final report is going to be a CSV, Excel, RTF or .RPT ?

Comment: What do you do? You mean you don't want to use Visual Studio?

Comment: I am not using Visual Studio. I am using SAP Crystal Reports software to make my report. I create the report with this software and then I send it to a third party who loads it on the server and I run this report through their web application.

Comment: This is gonna be a complicated scenario. Sorry can't help you this.